# unable to connect eclipse market place - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) Malformed reply from SOCKS server

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, eclipse-plugin

Trying to connect eclipse market place to install the plug-ins but getting this error.
I have added the proxy settings and selected the Active Provider to Manual

Error Details :-

INFO: Retrying connect
Jul 15, 2014 2:30:11 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Malformed reply from SOCKS server

Eclipse Details:-

Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
OS - Linux Ubundu GNOME 2.16.0

Do let me know your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround for this issue.

Window > Preferences > Network Connections >

Select the Active Provider as Manual.

And in the proxy entries add the authentication for http and https schemas.

leave the SOCKS authentication as "NO". if you set already just clear it.

The SOCKS was kept YES and that's the reason its not connecting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is still reproducing on STS 3.7.3.RELEASE.

See also the issue on [eclipse community forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/110146/) and the related bugs on [eclipse bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281472)...